# Can one acquire "tenure" through teaching or being something like a Research Associate at a university lab?

Tags: career-path, united-states, teaching, tenure-track, non-tenure

This question is specific to the United States.

Can one acquire something like "tenure" if either

(1) their primary / only responsibility is teaching undergraduate courses

and / or

(2) they work as a Research Scientist for a university lab but are not professors.

I am wondering about job security, basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Professor of the practice at Duke is a permanent position without tenure. It has levels: assistant, associate, and full. Contracts start at 3-4 years and get longer as you move up with 10 year contracts for full.

Comment: That's not a lot different than a lecturer position at Michigan except for the title.  A FT lecturer appointment is also a permanent position but without tenure.  I'm entering year 3 of my initial 3-yr appointment as a Lecturer III; when it renews, it will be as a Lecturer IV for another 3-yr term but with a "presumption of renewal".  Successive renewals will be for 5-year terms.

Comment: For comparison, Teaching Assistant Professors at Illinois have renewable one-year contracts; after lots of lobbying, Teaching Associate Professors and Teaching Professors in my department now have renewable _three_-year contracts.  (These positions are only a few years old; the campus is still getting used to the idea.)  The closest we have to "[adjective] professor of the practice" are "clinical [adjective] professors", who (I think) all have one-year contracts.

Comment: Rethinking my comment above, I want to clarify (for those not in academia)  that the "except for the title" is a truly big deal in academia.  Universities do not hand out PoP titles except rarely.  To get a PoP is a huge achievement.  Realistically, it's not easy to get any title that says "professor" in it as teaching faculty at most universities.  Lecturer is a title they give to most teaching faculty and it's title everyone who has it hates. (I'm always slightly uncomfortable when students call me "professor" knowing that's not my actual title.)

Answer (score 8):

No, generally speaking, tenure is not offered to teaching faculty, usually called lecturers, or research scientists at American universities.  The AAUP has long argued that teaching faculty should also be eligible for tenure and [they report](https://www.aaup.org/report/tenure-and-teaching-intensive-appointments) that a small number of universities have created tenure tracks for teaching faculty.  But it's rare.

That said, if you can get hired full-time as a lecturer, your job security is pretty good, mainly because (speaking from experience serving on the lecturer search committee here at Michigan) it's so hard to find qualified individuals who want the job, given that it's so dramatically less attractive to academics than a tenure track appointment.

Comment: But note that Michigan is an R1 university and so not typical of all universities (and colleges) in the US. The standards are very high for tenure.

Comment: There are many “regional comprehensive” institutions in the US where faculty can get tenureas professors llargely on their teaching record with very little research required.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I think we're splitting hairs.  Those institutions often still make a distinction between tenure track and lecturer positions, which do not lead to tenure.  It just doesn't take the same research achievements to achieve tenure.

Comment: There are also some universities that technically don't offer "tenure" to teaching faculty, but do have a very similar system called by a different name.  For example, the University of California has [Lecturer with Security of Employment](https://apo.ucsc.edu/policy/capm/514.285%20.html).

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, and there are some universities that have created Teaching Professor titles, which is the other big pain point in lecturer appointments.  (We've been pushing for that at Michigan, pointing out that the title is a big reason why people don't want the job but to no avail so far.)

Comment: @Lisa I'm not a professor (though the students call me that), I'm a lecturer (who's been pestering for a PoP title. :)  There's a LOT of age and gender discrimination in industry (don't get me started on Microsoft!) but as a 68-yo woman, I've encountered basically none as faculty at Michigan in CS.  If I'd realized how much nicer it is being faculty at a university than slaving in industry, I'd have gotten a PhD (I only have an MS) and been here *decades* ago.

Comment: At CUNY both Lecturers (essentially teaching faculty) and lab technicians can earn the equivalent of tenure.  For lecturers this is called a Certificate of Continuous Employment.

Comment: @Elin CUNY is one of the schools mentioned in that AAUP link I gave.

Comment: @NateEldredge Should have pointed out that UC is another of the schools mentioned in that AAUP link.

Answer (score 1):

Your first case is possible at some but not all US universities. There are many whose primary mission is teaching with only minor research responsibilities. The usual way it is put is that you "need to keep up with the field". But at many other universities, research is a major part of any tenure decision.

Your second scenario is probably much less likely. The titles you give often don't come with tenure, though in some top level places, Research Scientist would be more likely to be tenurable. But even then, some guidance of graduate students (i.e. "teaching") might be part of the job and evaluated in any tenure decision.

I'll note that at some very fine institutions (CMU, Duke, Stanford, ...) there is a special track for teaching faculty (Professor of the Practice is a common title) and these positions, while not tenurable, come with, say, *renewable* ten year contracts. But they also have high standards both for teaching and for "keeping up". In this case, keeping up usually means that you also publish, though publishing pedagogical work rather than strictly scientific work is probably mostly the norm. People that I know in these positions either have doctorates or some other outstanding qualifications as educators. The positions are very secure, even if not tenure, strictly speaking. (Information here supplied by a Duke PoP).

Comment: Professor of Practice is *rarely* tenurable.  (Offhand, I can't think of any US university that grants tenure for PoPs.)  [Stanford](https://facultyhandbook.stanford.edu/2-appointments-reappointments-and-promotions-professoriate), [Duke](https://provost.duke.edu/sites/all/files/FHB_Chap_3.pdf) and [CMU](https://www.cmu.edu/policies/faculty/appointments-teaching-track.html) *do not* offer tenure to teaching faculty.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton, maybe I got it wrong. I'll ask a few folks. The "moral equivalent of tenure" is there. Long term employment - certainly beyond any seven year limits.

Comment: Well, yes, that was my point in my answer:  If you're good enough to get hired as a FT lecturer, your job security is pretty good, precisely because it's so hard to find good people who want that job.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton Huh. I really thought Susan Rodger and Owen Astrachan had actual formal tenure at Duke, not just de-facto tenure.

Comment: @JeffE I'm not familiar with their specific situations but I see they're both PoPs.  [Duke's policy re: titles](https://admin.trinity.duke.edu/faculty-affairs/appointment-titles) is that a PoP is a non-tenure track position.  But my guess is their jobs are very secure, same as mine is as a full-time lecturer at Michigan, even without tenure.  At many (most?) universities, the only faculty who are really at risk of losing their jobs are non-tenured assistant professors and adjunct or affiliate faculty.

Comment: @JeffE, I've corrected my statement on PoP. Long, renewable contracts, but not tenure.